# Keep VC++ 2005 static library and your application in separate solutions

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries

I have successfully built a static library as described in this walkthrough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

In the example above, both the static library and the application are located within the **same solution** but I prefer to keep them in **separate solutions**. After separation, I can compile but cannot link, here is the error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol…
```

Then I tried the project level setting of my application `C/C++ / General / Additional include directories` to where my .h file resides.

I also set `.. Linker / General / Additional library directories` to where my .lib file is at.

I finally set `.. Linker / Input / Additional dependencies` to where my .lib file is at.

Again, I could compile but not link.  Here is the entire link error:

```
LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(double,double)" (?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
Release\StaticLibraryApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: The Additional dependencies setting must *name* the .lib, not just contain the directory in which it resides.  So it should say "MathFuncsLib.lib"

Comment: Wow, thank you Hans, that was what I was missing! The application now links.

Comment: Hans, you accurately pointed out that I had to add the lib file as an "Additional Dependency" which did solve my problem. But I am very curious about something, the Boost libraries have many different libs and it is not necessary to add the lib as a dependency, thus making it very easy to include any of the many Boost libs by simply specifying the header file. With Boost, you simply set the "VC++ Directories" to point to the Boost header and lib folders. Boost libs are avaiable to all apps, nothing more is required. What does Boost do different?

Comment: It uses `#pragma comment(lib, "mathfuncslib.lib")`, the way to inject a link dependency from code instead of using a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Your project should link against the library project. In the 2nd project properties, add a library path where .lib file is stored and also include path for header path. This should resolve the issue. Also make 1st project dependent on 2nd solution.

Have a look at below article how to add libraries:
http://www.lavishsoft.com/wiki/index.php/Visual_Studio_Paths

Comment: Hello, please see that in my original post, I did include the library path and the library header file into my application. This does work if both are contained within the same solution but I want them both in the same solution. I somehow missed your link, I am going to visit it now, thank you.